# How to use JSON variable in setInterval delay in Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, settimeout, setinterval

I am working on Angular 11 project. I want to loop the code after 'X' duration mentioned in JSON.data. Here is my following code snippet.

**data.json**

```
pageOrder: {
   pageDetails:[
   {
     "duration": 5
   },
   {
     "duration": 7
   }]
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
id: any = 0;
reloadFunction();
....
....
....
reloadFunction(): void {
    // most of your code
    console.log('wassup'); //**this should run after "duration", unfortunately its not working**

    setTimeout(this.reloadFunction, pageOrder[this.id].duration * 1000);

    this.id += 1;
    if (this.id === pageOrder.length) {
      console.log('wassup1', this.id);
      this.id = 0;
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, the code is looping only once, why???

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` calls the function in a different scope. `this` doesn't point to the object. You need to bind the object

```
setTimeout(this.reloadFunction.bind(this), pageOrder[this.id].duration * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :-

```
reloadFunction(): void {
    console.log('wassup'); 
    setTimeout(() => this.reloadFunction(), pageOrder[this.id].duration * 1000);

    this.id += 1;
    if (this.id === pageOrder.length) {
      console.log('wassup1', this.id);
      this.id = 0;
    }
  }
```